# Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to pass an object (a reference to the currently logged on user, basically) between two forms.  At the moment, I have something along these lines in the login form:

```
private ACTInterface oActInterface;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oActInterface = new ACTInterface(@"\\actserver\Database\Premier.pad",this.textUser.Text,this.textPass.Text);

        if (oActInterface.checkLoggedIn())
        {
            //user has authed against ACT, so we can carry on
            clients oClientForm = new clients(oActInterface);
            this.Hide();
            oClientForm.Show();
        }
        else...
```

on the next form (clients), I have:

```
public partial class clients : Form
{
    private ACTInterface oActInt {get; set;}

    public clients(ACTInterface _oActInt)
```

...which results in me getting:

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: 
parameter type 'support.ACTInterface' is less accessible than method    
'support.clients.clients(support.ACTInterface)'  
c:\work\net\backup\support\support\clients.cs   20  16  support
```

I don't really understand what the problem is - both fields are private, and accessed by the relevant public method from the form.  Googling doesn't really help, as it just points towards one element being public and the other private, which isn't the case here.

Anybody help?

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Constructor of `public` class `clients` is `public` but it has a parameter of type `ACTInterface` that is `private` (it is nested in a class?). You can't do that. You need to make `ACTInterface` at least as accessible as `clients`.

Comment: For more information check MSDN article on error [CS0051](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sscdk02.aspx)

Comment: This helped me.  I was trying to do the following:
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Name_Of_My_Model>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
The "Name_Of_My_Model" class wasn't set to either Public nor Private.  Turned out I NEEDED to set the "Name_Of_My_Model" (class) to public to be used in a "public" method that had a WebMethod decorator above it for an ajax call I was doing.

Comment: Even more information [Restrictions on Using Accessibility Levels(C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/restrictions-on-using-accessibility-levels)

Comment: And @EricMilliot-Martinez, your comment helped me. I needed to add Public to one of my classes as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 108):

Make the class public.

```
class NewClass
{

}
```

is the same as:

```
internal class NewClass
{

}
```

so the class has to be public

Comment: May anyone explain, please?

Comment: By default (leaving out the accessibility keyword) a class is internal and not publicly accessible. It's best to explicitly declare the accessibility of the class to show intent.

Comment: So to declare the first code properly you need: 
`public class NewClass
{

}`

Answer (score 33):

If sounds like the type `ACTInterface` is not `public`, but is using the default accessibility of either `internal` (if it is top-level) or `private` (if it is nested in another type).

Giving the type the `public` modifier would fix it.

Another approach is to make both the type and the method `internal`, if that is your intent.

The issue is not the accessibility of the *field* (`oActInterface`), but rather of the type `ACTInterface` itself.

Answer (score 12):

What is the accessibility of the type `support.ACTInterface`.  The error suggests it is not public.

You cannot expose a public method signature where some of the parameter types of the signature are not public.  It wouldn't be possible to call the method from outside since the caller couldn't construct the parameters required.

If you make `support.ACTInterface` public that will remove this error.  Alternatively reduce the accessibility of the form method if possible.

Answer (score 11):

```
parameter type 'support.ACTInterface' is less accessible than method    
'support.clients.clients(support.ACTInterface)'
```

The error says 'support.ACTInterface' is less accessible because you have made the interface as private, at least make it internal or make it public.

Answer (score 5):

When I received this error, I had a "helper" class that I did not declare as public that caused this issue inside of the class that used the "helper" class.  Making the "helper" class public solved this error, as in:

public ServiceClass
{
    public ServiceClass(HelperClass _helper)
    { }
}

**public** class HelperClass {} // Note the public HelperClass that solved my issue.

This may help someone else who encounters this.

Comment: Imagine that as a user of the ServiceClass you want to construct an object. How can you know what a HelperClass is unless it is set to public? This is the basic logic behind it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem doesn't seem to be with the variable but rather with the declaration of ACTInterface. Is ACTInterface declared as internal by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I hadone class in a file and I was passing a instance of that class to the constructor of my form in another file.
The problem was had declared the class without the public modifier : `class MyClass {}`

I could have solved it by changing it to `public class MyClass {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can get Parameter (class that have less accessibility) as `object` then convert it to your class by `as` keyword.

Comment: Don't you think? you could have added this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs when you want to use a classvariable in a new form, you should put the class definition in the

> Formname.Designer.cs

instead of the Formname.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my entity framework model, I found this error infecting several files in my solution. I simply right clicked on my .edmx file and my TT file and click "Run Custom Tool" and that had me right again after a restart of Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers that say make the type  **ActInterface** as public are right. I am only putting this post to explicitly mention why that's an issue

If a parameter to your public class constructor is **private** or **internal** qualified class, it means you wont be able to create an object of that parameter class from outside of the assembly and when you cannot instantiate the parameter object, how can you call this constructor to instantiate an object of this class ?

Comment: The other answers recommend to make the **type `ACTInterface`** public, not the **field  `oActInterface`**.

Answer (score -4):

Try making your constructor private like this:

```
private Foo newClass = new Foo();
```

Comment: Not really. This is due to nested protection.