# Parameter is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to pass a list from one form class to another. Here's the code:

```
List<Branch> myArgus = new List<Branch>();

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the selected branch name
    string selectedBranch = lbBranches.SelectedItem.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArgus.Count; i++)
    {
        if (myArgus[i]._branchName == selectedBranch)
        {
            // Open the BranchOverview form
            BranchOverview branchOverview = new BranchOverview(myArgus[i]);
            branchOverview.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Branch doesn't exist for some reason
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my `BranchOverview` class:

```
List<Branch> branch = new List<Branch>();

public BranchOverview(List<Branch> myArgus)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    branch = myArgus;
}
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Argus.Branch>' is less accessible than method 'Argus.BranchOverview.BranchOverview(System.Collections.Generic.List<Argus.Branch>)'
```

Comment: Yes, OK. So what specifically is your question? Do you not understand what the error message means? Or do you understand it but you don't know how to fix it? Or do you understand how to fix it, but you're stuck deciding between two different approaches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have to declare `Branch` to be public:

```
public class Branch {
  . . . 
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was kind of it, thanks. Within the `Branch` class I was creating other objects from classes which also weren't public, which is where it was getting me. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much, I learned OOP before but I still forget this.

Answer (score 10):

As the error message says, the type of all parameters of a method must be at least as accessible as the method itself.

You need to make your `Branch` class public if you are using it as a parameter in a public method.

```
public class Branch { .... } 
^^^^^^
```

Alternatively you could change your method to be `internal` instead of `public`.

```
internal BranchOverview(List<Branch> myArgus)
^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about "internal." It saved me a lot of time going through and changing compounding classes all to public (change one to public, more errors occurred.) For anyone interested, more information is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=VS.80).aspx .

Answer (score 2):

By default, fields of a class are `private` if no `access modifier` is present ...

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `BranchOverview` is `public`, which means that all types involved in its formal parameter list must also be `public`. Most probably you have not provided an accessibility specification for `Branch`, i.e. you have written

```
class Branch { ... }
```

which means that `Branch` is `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
List<Branch> myArgus = new List<Branch>();
```

to be public.