# Declaring a View + ViewModel as Internal

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Somehow I came across an issue I cannot figure out.

Assuming we have a View:

```
public partial class TestView : UserControl
    {
        public TestView(TestViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

And the injected ViewModel:

```
 class TestViewModel
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

This logically results in an error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'TestViewModel' is less
>   accessible than method 'TestView.TestView'

**So when I want to declare my View and ViewModel as internal:**

```
internal class TestViewModel
    {
        internal TestViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

This works:

```
partial class TestView : UserControl
    {
        TestView(TestViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't:

```
internal partial class TestView : UserControl
    {
        internal TestView(TestViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

**Why?**

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Partial declarations of 'TestView' have conflicting accessibility modifiers. But where and why? I thought a class is automatically internal when there is no modifier.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions if you want the reason. [Example one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726974/parameter-is-less-accessible-than-method), [example two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method).

Comment: This is not the answer to my Question. The `internal` modifier should be optional, but if i change it it causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because xaml consider your class as public where as your code behind says it is `internal`. Add this to your xaml `x:ClassModifier="internal"`

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.TestView " x:ClassModifier="internal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But Why does it work without any modifier? Shouldn't this be the same like `internal`?

Comment: @JohannesWanzek By default [x:ClassModifier is public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754029%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah `x:ClassModifier` is public in XAML, But in My code I don't declare any modifiere, which means it should be internal by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you don't declare in xaml and code behind it will be internal