# Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I keep getting:-

> Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method

I have no idea what's wrong, please help

```
List<receipt> _list;
        string _total, _cash, _change, _date;

        public Form8(List<receipt> datasource, string total, string cash, string change, string date)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _list = datasource;
            _total = total;
            _cash = cash;
            _change = change;
            _date = date;
        }



   class receipt
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productname { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string Total {  get { return string.Format("{0}kz", price * quantity); } }



    }
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that `class Form8` and `Form8()` are public and that receipt has no modifier or is `internal`

Comment: Can you show receipt? Please post the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter is less accessible than method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726974/parameter-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Comment: @john yes class form8 is public

Comment: @Marcio and does receipt have a modifier (public, internal, private if it's a nested class)? You should post the code for receipt so people don't have to guess. It will, however, be the same situation as the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: class receipt
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productname { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string Total {  get { return string.Format("{0}kz", price * quantity); } }



    }

Comment: @Marcio It's the same as the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726974/parameter-is-less-accessible-than-method) then.

Comment: @Marcio please read about [modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) :)

Comment: @john will do! thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make receipt public. You can't request a list of those in your form8 constructor if the caller maybe can't even access receipt.