# Inconsistent accessibility issue

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'RR.DAL.LINQSqlCLient.StaticReport' is less accessible than method 'RR.BLL.AuditTrail.InsertStaticReportAudit(RR.DAL.LINQSqlCLient.StaticReport, string)'    
D:\My Projects\ASP Projects\Development\RapidReportTool\Working Directory\App_Code\BLL\AuditTrail.cs
```

This is my code:

```
public static void InsertStaticReportAudit(StaticReport staticReport, string filterString)
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuditTrail"] != null)
    {
        AuditTrail CurrAuditTrail = (AuditTrail)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuditTrail"];

        AuditTrailReports auditTrailReport = new AuditTrailReports();
        auditTrailReport.ID = AuditTrailReports.Insert(CurrAuditTrail.ID, staticReport.ID, filterString, DateTime.Now, true);

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuditTrailReport"] = auditTrailReport;
    }
}
```

The parameter StaticReport class:

```
partial class StaticReport
{
    public bool BelongsToReportCategory(int reportCategoryID)
    {
        //If there is an entry StaticReport_ReportCategories junction table,
        //then this static report belongs to the report category

        RapidReportDataContext db = new RapidReportDataContext();
        var query = from sr_sc in db.StaticReport_ReportCategories
                               where sr_sc.StaticReportID == this.ID && sr_sc.ReportCategoryID == reportCategoryID
                               select sr_sc;

        if (query.Count() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Check the other partial definition of the `StaticReport` class. See if it's `private` or `internal`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a public method `InsertStaticReportAudit` having a parameter with type `StaticReport`. This type **is not** public. A caller outside your assembly would not be able to call the method and that is why the compiler doesn't accept it.

You have to make `StaticReport` public or `InsertStaticReportAudit` non-public.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite literal: the type `StaticReport` is not public.

Since it's a partial class you may have to look at both declarations, the 'main' declaration should use the `public` modifier.

The default access level is `internal` and you cannot use an internal type in the signature of a public method. It would be impossible to call.