# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'x' is less accessible than method 'y'

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, parameters

```
public partial class buyer : Form
{

   Client AbClient;
    public buyer(Client cli)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AbClient = cli;
    }
```

The function in which is throwing up the error.

```
public class Client {
}
```

Client is the class where the problem seems to be.

```
private void CheckAuth()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!sAuth.IsAlive)
            {
                if(abClient.isAuthSucessful)
                    Application.Run(new buyer(abClient));
                break;  
            } 
        }
    }
```

This is where the Autobuyer form is called from. (Inside the first form which is started by the main())

I still don't know how to fix this, I've of course searched but no one seems to have the answer that works in my situation.

Comment: What are `x` and `y` in your particular error message?

Comment: Provide us the real error message you got and the relevant code and we might be able to answer your question. As is, not so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your AbClient needs to be declared as public, as at the moment it's private by default. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cx03xt0t.aspx) - "The return type and parameter types of a method must be at least as accessible as the method itself."

Comment: Why? :/ strange one.