# I get the error message "Inconsistent accessibility"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, methods

What is wrong?

I am getting the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'List<Employee>' is less accessible than method 'Profile.GetEmployee(byte)'

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe that means that the `Employees` object is not public.

Comment: You should have added the code, not a screenshot. Or else get ready for a storm of downvotes! Don't look at me frowning! Relax, I didn't `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to discern what the problem is.  Usually you get this error when you have inconsistent member availability.  My guess is that your Employee entity isn't public.

If you post your Profile and Employee classes, I may be able to provide more input.

You also might want to check here: [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)