# C#: Can't seem to wrap my head around a compile error

Tags: c#

I'm facing a compilation issue in "PromoteEmployee" within "public static void PromoteEmployee(List employeeList, IsPromotable IsEligibleToPromote)".

Would appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how I should go about this.

EDIT:

The error is:
"Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Program.IsPromotable' is less accessible than method 'Program.Employee.PromoteEmployee(List, Program.IsPromotable)'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test1",
            Salary = 5000,
            Experience = 5
        });

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test2",
            Salary = 2000,
            Experience = 1
        });

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test3",
            Salary = 4000,
            Experience = 4
        });

        IsPromotable isPromotable = new IsPromotable(Promote);

        Employee.PromoteEmployee(empList, isPromotable);
    }

    public static bool Promote(Employee emp)
    {
        if (emp.Experience >= 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    delegate bool IsPromotable(Employee empl);

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }

        public static void PromoteEmployee(List<Employee> employeeList, IsPromotable IsEligibleToPromote)
        {
            foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
            {

                if (IsEligibleToPromote(employee))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(employee.Name + " promoted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us a hint by telling us what the compiler error says.

Comment: What is the error? What line does it happen on? Give us something to go on, please.

Comment: Is it this line `IsPromotable isPromotable = new IsPromotable(Promote);` ???

Comment: the delegate is private.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error I get compiling your program is:

```
(67:28) Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Program.IsPromotable' is less accessible than method 'Program.Employee.PromoteEmployee(System.Collections.Generic.List<Program.Employee>, Program.IsPromotable)'
```

This error occurs because `PromoteEmployee` is `public`, but `IsPromotable` is private.

> If somebody from outside class Program wants to call `PromoteEmployee`, he can't do that, because he can't create an instance of `Program.IsPromotable`, because it's private to `Program`.

-- https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett

To fix it make `IsPromotable` `internal` or `public` so that others outside `Program` can create it.

Alternatively you can make `PromoteEmployee` private.

Comment: @DStanley you're right, thanks

Comment: Point being, if somebody *from outside class Program* wants to call `PromoteEmployee`, he can't do that, because he can't create an instance of `Program.IsPromotable`, because it's private to `Program`. So the compiler warns you that you're doing something that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks @EdPlunkett nice description, quoted in the answer.

Comment: @JosephEarl Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working dotnetfiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4iuQjt

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test1",
            Salary = 5000,
            Experience = 5
        });

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test2",
            Salary = 2000,
            Experience = 1
        });

        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Test3",
            Salary = 4000,
            Experience = 4
        });

        IsPromotable isPromotable = new IsPromotable(Promote);

        Employee.PromoteEmployee(empList, isPromotable);
    }

    public static bool Promote(Employee emp)
    {
        if (emp.Experience >= 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public delegate bool IsPromotable(Employee empl);

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }

        public static void PromoteEmployee(List<Employee> employeeList, IsPromotable IsEligibleToPromote)
        {
            foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
            {

                if (IsEligibleToPromote(employee))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(employee.Name + " promoted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```