# Problem with model encapsulation in business logic layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, asp.net-core

I have a typical application with Controllers, Services, Repositories. So, there are 2 projects:

- ASP.NET Core WebAPI with controllers
- Core with all business logic

The WebAPI should know only about services from Core. In the Core I have public classes (services) that returns DTOs, but these services depends on DbContext that I want to mark as `internal`. Of course I can't

> Error CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'DevicesDbContext' is less accessible than method
>   'DeviceService.DeviceService(DevicesDbContext, IMapper)'

I'm using EF Core and [instead of own Repositories I use DbContext](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/). I have entity model that I have to use only in Core project. Could you please advice how can I achieve that?

For example my model is:

```
internal class Device
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

DbContext:

```
internal class DevicesDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Device> Devices {get;set;}
}
```

Service:

```
public class DeviceService : IDeviceService
{
   public DeviceService(DevicesDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
   { 
   }
   ..
}
```

I got that error in constructor of DeviceService.  It is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method) because I know what that error mean and how to fix that. Here I asked about design or architecture of this approach  because I need to avoid of using models and dbcontext in WebAPI directly

Comment: May I ask why you want to make DevicesDbContext internal? It seems to me that Device & DeviceDbContext should both be public. Secondly, you can put your DTO models in a new core project. That might make your responsibilities more obvious. Maybe try to set DbContext to protected instead of internal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Comment: @ZakkDiaz I want to make it internal to avoid using it directly in WebAPI

Comment: "design or architecture" is a little broad for SO. You *might* (as in, you should read their help center first) be able to ask this on [softwareengineering.se], but I think there, as here, they prefer a bit more specificity about what you're looking for.

Comment: @Greg I register it in DI in Core project. I didn't say the I want to inject context without registering it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Repositories to guard data access (which generally still return Entities, not DTOs, so Entities need to be public) then the real question is:
"Why do you want to avoid using the DbContext & Entities in your Web API?"

Entity Framework is a framework. It's purpose is to facilitate data access to make your code easier to write and easier to understand. Just as you chose to use the .Net framework and leverage things like Linq, Generics, etc. by chossing EF you should seek to leverage everything it offers.

If you absolutely must keep the context and entities out of the API assembly references, or want to centralize business logic involving entities between a Web API and another set of MVC controllers then you're looking at building an anemic API.  In this case:

Services.DLL -- References DbContext, entities..

```
public interface ISomethingService
{
  IEnumerable<SomeDto> GetSome(/*params*/);
}

public class SomethingService : ISomethingService
{
    public SomethingService(SomeDbContext context) 
    { // Init stuff. 
    }

    IEnumerable<SomeDto> ISomethingService.GetSome()
    {
       // Get some stuff and return DTOs.
    }
}
```

Web API DLL -- Only references DTOs.

```
public class SomeAPI : ISomethingService
{
    private ISomethingService Service { get; set; }
    public SomeAPI(ISomethingService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeDto> GetSome()
    {
        return Service.GetSome();
    }
}
```

The API is anemic in that it just passes requests through to a common service and forwards the response. The API doesn't need to implement the same interface, it can simply accept a reference to the service and consume it, passing through whatever parameters to get the DTOs that it will pass back.

The downside of this approach is that to modify the service you're flipping between the API and the Services layer vs. just working within the API.  I don't favor using approaches like this because APIs and such often need to consider details like filtering, paging, etc. so I want to leverage the excellent LINQ capabilities that EF offers. I also leverage EF's `IQueryable` support heavily to keep my data access layer simple and compact, letting consuming services decide how to fetch the detail they need. Masking this with an extra service boundary adds complexity and inefficiencies as it either results in complex code, lots of very similar functions, and/or wasted memory/processing to return data that is not needed.