# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ICourseRepository' is less accessible than method ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to dtonet. I created repository and injected it into controller but got this error in controller constructor

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IContactRepository' is less accessible than method 'ContactController.ContactController(IContactRepository)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229504/inconsistent-accessibility-parameter-type-is-less-accessible-than-method)

Comment: Well we can't see either of them, but: what are their respective accessibility levels? Public? Private? Internal? Not specified? And is either / both nested inside another type? If so, what is the accessibility of that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set `IContactRepository` as `public` in the file it is defined.

```
public interface IContactRepository {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I changed the interface from this

```
Interface ICourseRepository{
        Contact GetContact(int id);
        IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContact();
        Contact Add(Contact contact);
        Contact Delete(int id);
}
```

to this

```
Public Interface ICourseRepostory{
        Contact GetContact(int id);
        IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContact();
        Contact Add(Contact contact);
        Contact Delete(int id);
}
```

Comment: Yes just as I answered,